# Reduce Jboss Memory Usage

Tags: java, jvm, jboss5.x

On starting JbossAS 5.1 server on Linux:

```
26204 jboss     20   0 4874m 1.3g  12m S 144.0 11.4   1:45.50 java
```

This is before any class-loading.

It starts with minimum 1g (RES) memory. How can i reduce this?

Is there any-way we can suppress memory usages?

Comment: Is it a JBoss AS or a JBoss EAP?

Comment: Which OS / kernel are you using ?

Comment: JBoss 5 loads every jar in your application, regardless of whether your application uses it. Similarly, there are a number of services that can possibly be eliminated if you aren't using them, such as Quartz. Search for "jboss slimming" in your favorite search engine.

Comment: Not an answer but if you're not tied to 5.x series, give 7.x series a try.

Answer (score 0):

inside your %JAVA_HOME%\bin directory (the linux equivelant)

Check the run.conf file for:

```
if [ "x$JAVA_OPTS" = "x" ]; then
 JAVA_OPTS="-Xms128m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000"
fi
```

I am running 5.1.0.GA on a very old PC, and having has lots of memory errors during start up i removed this specification from the JAVA_OPTS spec. I did this in windows so the batch syntax is different, but essentially, i just removed this option completely. It stopped the server from moaning about memory, but i don't know if you can use these options to restrict the memory usage further.

Not really an answer, but you might find it helps